# What the heck is Firefox doing to my nav?

Tags: css, firefox

Alright, I'm completely stumped by this one. Firefox (FF 11/OS X) is rendering a white line at the bottom of my nav on http://ntcc.johnmbjerke.com/ but it goes away as soon as you hover on one of the items or scroll down the page and come back up.

I've messed with every seemingly related item with no luck. Any ideas?

Screenshot here: http://d.pr/5gKE

Comment: Pare it down to a simplest-possible test case. (Delete code until you cannot delete anymore without 'fixing' the problem.) In the process you will likely find your problem; if you don't, then you have a properly simple example for people to help with. You should do this every time you run into a problem involve complex parts that you don't understand.

Comment: Also...I can't reproduce your problem using FF11/Win7. All the more reason for you to pare it down.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem, post screenshot.

Comment: No problem here either with FF11 under Linux.

Comment: I can see the issue on FF11, Mac OS X. Very dodgy. If I disable the css property **background-size: cover** on section.masthead the line disappears, so I'm guessing it has something to do with this property.

Comment: It does look like it's related to background-size:cover. Any ideas for workarounds? Seems like a rendering bug.

Comment: @bjerkeweb take a look at my solution below, should fix it for you. And if it works, don't forget to mark the answer accepted - looks like you already made the change on the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually not a white line, but rather sub-pixel rendering due to the `background-size` property as the others have correctly identified in their comments above.  There is no way to avoid this 1px sub-pixel rendering because it comes from the background-size property and how it is rendering the image.

Your best bet is to shift the background-position -1px on the y-axis.  This means that the sub-pixel rendering will still happen, but it will occur at the bottom where the 1px of white will not be visible to the user.

Just change your `background-position: center center` to `background-position: center -1px`

Here's a screenshot after the change: http://d.pr/rOX9